# Facebook Android Login Screen WebViewCoreThread exiting due to uncaught exception

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, oauth, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement Facebook for Android in my app. I am running my app on a device with Android 2.0 .

I followed the instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/ to create a login screen but I continually encounter an error.

I see a login button, which I click. This brings me to a username and password entry screen, on which I enter my information and click Login. But once I click Login, my app crashes and I get the following error.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4607): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.SslErrorHandler.handleMessage(SslErrorHandler.java:62)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

And this is followed by:

```
ERROR/ActivityThread(4607): Activity com.facebook.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.webkit.BrowserGateReceiver@47b94148 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.facebook.LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.webkit.BrowserGateReceiver@47b94148 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:797)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:608)
    at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiverInternal(ApplicationContext.java:813)
    at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:800)
    at android.app.ApplicationContext.registerReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:794)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:308)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:308)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.registerReceiver(LoadListener.java:1855)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.<init>(LoadListener.java:191)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.getLoadListener(LoadListener.java:163)
    at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.startLoadingResource(BrowserFrame.java:554)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeAddData(Native Method)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.commitLoad(LoadListener.java:1256)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:257)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I have searched unsuccessfully for an answer to this question for two days and I cannot find anything. I think that the issue may be that my phone's Android version is too old. I can post my code if need be, but it is exactly the same as can be found at the above link. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my activity class:

```
public class FacebookScreen extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int SPLASH = 0;
private static final int SELECTION = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTION +1;

private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_login_screen);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[SPLASH] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
    fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

private boolean isResumed = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(SELECTION, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }
}

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
}
```

And here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.SelectionFragment"
          android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment android:name="com.example.SplashFragment"
          android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android versions prior to 2.2 has a bug in the webkit code causing these null pointer exceptions. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7900

Facebook SDK 3.0 has a minimum Android version of 2.2 in the manifest - maybe because of this bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a code sample. Its throwing a NULLPointerException which is probably why the Intent is leaking. If you share a snippet we could atleast get an idea where its going wrong

Comment: Ok, thanks. I posted my main class. Tell me if there's anything else you need.

Comment: You renamed com.facebook.scrumptious in your layout?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did rename it. I have included that file above as well.